# Qual a diferença entre usar .on() e .click()?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Qual a diferença entre declarar um event listener com jQuery para pegar o clique em um elemento desta forma:

```
$("#elemento").on("click", function() {
    ...
});
```

E desta outra forma:

```
$("#elemento").click(function() {
    ...
});
```

Dá na mesma?

Comment: É a mesma coisa. A diferença é que um é mais curto que o outro.